# ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner, cordova-plugins

Working with this, https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner and running into this error:

```
2014-12-08 21:03:34.159 Stacktive[38198:13141188] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

2014-12-08 21:03:34.159 Stacktive[38198:13141188] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [

"org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner33518157",

"org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner",

"scan",

[

]

]
```

But when I check for plugins existing.. I get this:

```
$ cordova plugins ls
com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner 2.0.1 "BarcodeScanner"
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One reads "cordova" and the other "phonegap". Could this be causing the problem?